# TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

```
# -*- coding : utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import StringIO


class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.url = tk.Entry()
        self.url.get()
        self.url.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.button = tk.Button(text="Download", command=self.get_url)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label = tk.Label(text="Name")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.path = tk.Entry()
        self.path.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def get_url(self):
        self.r = requests.get(self.url.get())
        self.i = Image.open(StringIO(self.r.content))
        self.i.save(self.path.get())


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    w = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is my code.I'm beging to study classes in python and trying to write a simple GUI app to download images from entered URL's, but there's a problem with this part:
self.i = Image.open(StringIO(self.r.content)). 
Please, explain me what I do wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.r.content` is binary data (a `bytes` object), but `StringIO` is for *textual data*. You want to use `io.BytesIO` here instead:

```
from io import BytesIO

self.i = Image.open(BytesIO(self.r.content))
```